# Scaling Images with OpenLayers

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, image

I have the same image (exactly the same dimensions) in Google Maps as in OpenStreetMap, but the scaling of the image in OSM is totally different. The scaling in Google Maps is after my opinion the correct one.

Google Maps:
[image: Picture in Google Maps]

OpenStreetMap: 
[image]

As you can see, the image boundaries are in Google Maps not even near those, of the image in OpenStreetMap.

My question is, can I add a limitation to the image boundaries in OSM?
My code for the image is the following:

```
var layer_image = new ol.layer.Image({
   source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
       url: '../static/kml/' + href,
       imageExtent: merc(west, south, east, north)
   })
});
```

EDIT:

```
function initializeMap() {
var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
});

map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [raster],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [1728012.45558, 5982976.33295],
        zoom: 7,
        projection: projection
    })
});
return map;
```

}

EDIT2: I'm still having this problem, I experimented with the `ol.source.ImageStatic` `imageSize`and `imageExtent` option but I didn't get any usefull results.

Comment: What projections do you set at your OL and within the KML? What is the source of the raster data?

Comment: I edited it, I hope that is that what you ment

Comment: @Mapper I have added the things you asked me too, sry i forgott to tag you